# Derivation of diode voltage in three phase full wave diode rectifier

Tags: rectifier, formula-derivation

Considering ideal diode in 3 phase full wave diode rectifier we can present the system in picture below.

[image]

I found the final equation for \$v_{D6}\$, but can not figure it out how it was derived. 
\$v_{D6} = u_{st} + \frac{L_i}{2L_i+L_0} (u_{rs}-v_0)\$

Can someone please help me with derivation of this equation(s).

Comment: What is v0? Is v_rs the same as u_rs?

Comment: looks right. Just use KVL and ignore phase. v*o* = V(Rout)

Comment: I will update equation in question but short answer is yes, v_rs is equal to u_rs.
Values of v0 is voltage drop over load resistor R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so the derivation was found with hint from [Tony Stewart Sunnyskyguy EE75](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/17574/tony-stewart-sunnyskyguy-ee75).

As always in analysing eletrical circuits we use KVL.
From picture in question we can write two equations

1. First we write the equation of conductiong path $$ u_{rs}-L_i\frac{di_0}{dt}-v_{D1}-L_0\frac{di_0}{dt}-v_0-v_{D5}-L_i\frac{di_0}{dt}=0 $$
   $$ \frac{di_0}{dt}=\frac{u_{rs}-v_0}{2L_i+L_0} $$
2. Next we can write equation for non conducting path from point \$t\$ to point \$r\$ ignoring \$v_0\$ and we get $$ u_{st}-v_{D6}-L_i\frac{di_0}{dt}=0$$
3. with putting two equations together we get $$ v_{D6} = u_{st} + \frac{L_i}{2L_i+L_0} (u_{rs}-v_0) $$